# How to load images in angular other than default assets folder

Tags: angular, angular9, angular11, angular12

I have a  folder directory structure here:
[image]

I have provided the image path in html.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="../../ecommerce/assets/images/bannerimg.png" alt=" ">
```

configured in angular json
[image]

But is not loaded
[image]

Its working well in default assets/images directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your path for the src property of your image tag as: `app/ecommerce/assets/images/bannerimg.png`